# merge 2 complex lists in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am programming in silverlight (c# .net)

lets say I have a list of type "data"

```
    public class data    
{
    public string QUOTE_ID { get; set; }
    public string EVENT_ACTION_CD { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADAPTIV_CODE { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is some of the data comes from 1 database and the other data comes from another, so right now i get the data in 2 steps - so i have something like this (using random numbers):

```
input1 = new List<data> //data return from database 1 
//(the data is actually returned as a datable which i convert to a list      
//to put to a datagrid, but the end result is shown below)
{
    new data { QUOTE_ID = "1", EVENT_ACTION_CD = "2"},
    new Project { QUOTE_ID = "2", EVENT_ACTION_CD = "4"},
    new Project { QUOTE_ID = "3", EVENT_ACTION_CD = "5"}
};

input2 = new List<data> //data return from database 2    
{
    new data { QUOTE_ID = "1", CUSTOMER_NAME = "2", ADAPTIV_CODE ="5"},
    new Project { QUOTE_ID = "2", CUSTOMER_NAME = "4", ADAPTIV_CODE = "5"},
    new Project { QUOTE_ID = "3", CUSTOMER_NAME = "5", ADAPTIV_CODE = "7"}
};
```

so i should have 2 lists like
input1:

```
(1, 2, null, null
2, 4, null, null
3, 5, null, null)
```

and 
input2:

```
(1, null, 2, 5
2, null, 4, 5
3. null, 5, 7)
```

how do i join them together to form one input list to become

```
(1, 2, 2, 5
2, 4, 4, 5
3, 5, 5, 7)
```

Comment: How does your Project class relate to your data class?

Comment: typo from a copy/paste, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linq with a join operator.

See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
var resultList = (from item in input1 
                 join item2 in input2 on item2.QUOTE_ID equals input2.QUOTE_ID
                 let item.CUSTOMER_NAME = item2.CUSTOMER_NAME
                 let item.ADAPTIV_CODE = item2.ADAPTIV_CODE 
                 select item).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal for loop would work for you:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input1.Count; i++){
 if(input1[i].QUOTE_ID == null) input1[i].QUOTE_ID = input2[i].QUOTE_ID;
 if(input1[i].EVENT_ACTION_CD == null) input1[i].EVENT_ACTION_CD = input2[i].EVENT_ACTION_CD;
 if(input1[i].CUSTOMER_NAME == null) input1[i].CUSTOMER_NAME = input2[i].CUSTOMER_NAME;
 if(input1[i].ADAPTIV_CODE == null) input1[i].ADAPTIV_CODE = input2[i].ADAPTIV_CODE;
}
```

The result will be saved into the `input1`. The code also supposes `input1` and `input2` have the same `Count`.

Answer (score 0):

var input3 = input1.Join(
     input2, 
     d1 => d1.QUOTE_ID, 
     d2 => d2.QUOTE_ID,
     (d1, d2) => new data() { 
        QUOTE_ID = d1.QUOTE_ID, 
        EVENT_ACTION_CD = d1.EVENT_ACTION_CD, 
        CUSTOMER_NAME = d2.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
        ADAPTIV_CODE = d2.ADAPTIV_CODE 
     }
);

Comment: to use LINQ method, .NET 3.5 is required.